# Creating Google plus sign in

Tags: php, google-plus

I am trying to create a google plus sign in for my webpage and i'm trying to create this php   quickstart app to start with.

https://developers.google.com/+/quickstart/php

However I don't know how to execute steps 5 and 6. I'm uploading the files directly to my domain so I don't really understand where do I need to install composer and the dependencies. I tried signing in but I get a 401 error. Is it because I skipped these steps? or something else?

These are the steps:

Install Composer:

> 5. Install composer `curl -s https://getcomposer.org/installer | php`
>      Execute composer to install the quick-start dependencies:
> 6. Execute composer to install the quick-start dependencies: `php composer.phar install`

Comment: Please include **all** relevant information **within your post**. One day that URL might go dark and then no one will ever be able to know what you meant by "steps 5 and six".

Comment: The quickstart app assumes your on unix, If your not get composer for windows, RTM: https://getcomposer.org/download/